# Instagram api - Video mp4 format

Tags: html, html5-video, instagram

Im using the instagram api by tag name (https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/TAG/media/recent?client_id=XXX&callback=callbackfunction). From this array of objects, Im planning to use only the videos.

Videos are in mp4 format, which does not work properly in firefox. I cannot create new videos in another format since the point is to show the information dynamically.

Is there any solution for mp4 format? Any fallback solution for browsers and mobile phones? Any instagram parameter to get videos in other formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert them but playing them using the [mediaelement](http://mediaelementjs.com/) (MEJS) plugin, which is supported in a wide variety of browsers and devices.

Once you get the video's URL from the API response like

```
http://distilleryvesper3-15.ak.instagram.com/b0ce80e6b91111e3a16a122b8b9af17f_101.mp4
```

you can set a (HTML5) `<video>` tag for each of them like

```
<video class="video-player" width="340" height="340" preload="none" src="http://distilleryvesper3-15.ak.instagram.com/b0ce80e6b91111e3a16a122b8b9af17f_101.mp4" poster="http://photos-h.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-ash/10011258_688891784492223_294700298_s.jpg"></video>
```

and use this script to initialize them with MEJS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('video').mediaelementplayer();
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7zgcx508/)**

Answer (score 0):

For browsers that do not support the playing of MP4, you need to revert to using a Flash player (which is what the MediaElementJS player mentioned by JFK does).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use mediaelementplayer to play your videos. It will simply use the flash fallback on all non webkit browsers since the Instagram API only supplys an mp4.

This plugin actually does exactly what you need.

http://codecanyon.net/item/simple-instagram-video/full_screen_preview/5039255